# Could incorrect table relations be the reason of inability to enter data into Ms Access Form?

Tags: forms, ms-access, foreign-keys, relationship

I've been asked to created a Form based on a wrong table relations.
I have 2 tables:

Clients:
[Name], [Gender] - both are text fields

and

Gender:
[Gender] - only one text field

I needed to create a query to display [Name] field from the Clients table and [Gender] field from Gender table.  All fields are text, no indexes.

When I created a query and then a Form, based on that query - my Form is unable to add a new record(s). Or - to edit an existing one.

Is it because of the incorrect (not appropriate) relations, when I really should have [GenderID] in the main table and [GenderID] + [Gender] in my additional (Gender) table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you haven't change  you recordset  to **Dynaset (Inconsistent Updates)** 
1- While your query in design model get property sheet of your query 
2-change  you recordset  to **Dynaset (Inconsistent Updates)**

That should  do it

Comment: Thank you, BData!  Changing Dynaset in properties to Dynaset (Inconsistent Updates) helped!
Also - the main cause that I couldn't edit or add data was "Group By" in my query.